# Cannot connect to minikube deployment on browser on MacOS

Tags: node.js, docker, macos, kubernetes, minikube

I start `minikube` with:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

I have a simple Node.js app:

```js
import express from "express";
import os from "os";

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const helloMessage = `Hello from the ${os.hostname()}`;
    console.log(helloMessage);
    res.send(helloMessage);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Web server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I create a deployment with `NodePort` type:

```
kubectl expose deployment k8s-web-hello --type=NodePort --port=3000
kubectl get svc
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
k8s-web-hello   NodePort    10.96.41.105   <none>        3000:30734/TCP   10m
kubernetes      ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          9h
minikue ip
192.168.49.2
```

If I use `minikube ssh`, I can `curl 192.168.49.2:30734` or `curl 10.96.41.105:3000` and get the expected output.

However, if I use:

```
minikube service k8s-web-hello
  Starting tunnel for service k8s-web-hello.
  Opening service default/k8s-web-hello in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

It opens a new tab on my web browser (Chrome) but it cannot load: `http://192.168.49.2:30734/`.

I have tried suggested solutions in [#11193](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11193) including:

```
minikube service k8s-web-hello --url

  Starting tunnel for service k8s-web-hello.
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

I get the same result:
[image]

```
minikube version
minikube version: v1.25.2
commit: 362d5fdc0a3dbee389b3d3f1034e8023e72bd3a7

kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.1", GitCommit:"3ddd0f45aa91e2f30c70734b175631bec5b5825a"

Mac OS
12.4 (21F79)
M1 chip

Google Chrome
Chrome is up to date
Version 102.0.5005.61 (Official Build) (arm64)

Docker Desktop for MacOS
Version
4.8.2 (79419)
```